# Typescript: how to format the date and time format

Tags: typescript

I have this date value from an API response: 
Sat Feb 04 2017 10:00:00 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time) 
But, we I want to get its only the date part, like 'yyyy-MM-dd'. Then save this date value into a date variable rather than a string variable 
Moreover, how to save the certain time 10:00:00 into a date type variable by Typescript as well?